# Display single item in Mongo Db using meteor js using template based subscription

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, publish-subscribe, meteor-blaze

I don't know what the problem is, i have this snippet to display single items but it does not work as suppose, What's do i make right?

publication file:

```
Meteor.publish('SingleSchool', function (myslug) {
        check(myslug, String);
        if (!this.userId) {
            throw new Meteor.Error('Not authorized');
            return false;
        } else {
            return SchoolDb.find({slug: myslug});
        }
    })
```

template base subscription:

```
Template.view.onCreated(function () {
    var instance = this;
    instance.autorun(function () {
        var slug = FlowRouter.getParam('myslug');
        return Meteor.subscribe('SingleSchool', slug);
    });
});
```

the route:

```
FlowRouter.route('/school/:myslug', {
  name: 'view',
  action: function (params) {
    BlazeLayout.render('sidebarschool', {sidebars: 'view'});
  }
})
```

the template file:

```
<template name="view">  
    {{#if currentUser}}
    {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady }}
        {{#if SingleSchool}}
            {{#with SingleSchool}}
                <p>{{varibablecalled}}</p>
            {{/with}}
        {{else}}
            <p>Loading...</p>
        {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

It goes to the slug but no data is displayed for other contents. The slug in the route works fine.[image: routing with slug displays a blank page]

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize your `SingleSchool` collection you're trying to read from in the template?

Also, don't forget that this is *collection*, so you should do `SingleSchool.findOne({slug:...})` to obtain needed item.

Btw, your template file looks like messed up: two `<template...>` tags.